# Programa para separar pares e impares i contarlos

Tags: javascript

No me recorre el for ni me da una respuesta por pantalla al ejecutar este código para separar 10 pares e impares y contarlos. El programa ha de dar este resultado: https://gyazo.com/a726ba18779341b57914b5fb97abce13
El programa es el siguiente:

```js
 var parells = "";
      var senars = "";
      var numparells = 0;
      var numsenars = 0;
      document.write("<h1>Numbers List</h1>");
      document.write("<ol>");
      for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
        var num = parseInt(prompt("Dona'm un número menor al número de capítols que té One Piece"));
       if(num % 2 === 0){
        parells = parells + ("<li>" + number + "</li>"); 
        numparells = numparells + 1;
       }
        else{
         senars = senars + ("<li>" + number + "</li>"); 
         numsenars = numsenars + 1;
        }
      }
      document.write("<li>Evens</li>");
      document.write("<ul>");
      document.write(parells);
      document.write("</ul>");
      document.write("<li>Odds</li>");
      document.write("<ul>");
      document.write(senars);
      document.write("</ul>");
      document.write("</ol>");
      document.write("The total numbers of even numbers read has been: " + numparells);
        document.write("The total numbers of even numbers read has been: " + numsenars);
```

Comment: La variable ```number``` nunca fue dclarada, en lugar de eso sustituye por ```num```

Comment: Falta incluir la descripción de lo que hace el código y el error textual. Si no lo has hecho aún, por favor lee [mcve].

Comment: El prompt no devuelve un `Number` sino un `String` además de cambiar `number` por `num` añade `Number(num)` al if. `if(Number(num) % 2 === 0){`

Answer (score 0):

Además de cambiar `number` por `nu`m, como ya te han indicado en los comentarios, el número a descomponer creo que debería solicitarse una sola vez antes de iniciar el bucle, y utilizar ese número como límite para el bucle `for`, de modo que consultes en cada ciclo si el valor que se incrementa (`i`) es impar o par.

```js
var parells = "";
  var senars = "";
  var numparells = 0;
  var numsenars = 0;
  document.write("<h1>Numbers List</h1>");
  document.write("<ol>");
  var num = parseInt(prompt("Dona'm un número menor al número de capítols que té One Piece"));
  for(var i=1; i<=num; i++){    
   if(i % 2 === 0){
    parells = parells + ("<li>" + i + "</li>"); 
    numparells = numparells + 1;
   }
    else{
     senars = senars + ("<li>" + i + "</li>"); 
     numsenars = numsenars + 1;
    }
  }
  document.write("<li>Evens</li>");
  document.write("<ul>");
  document.write(parells);
  document.write("</ul>");
  document.write("<li>Odds</li>");
  document.write("<ul>");
  document.write(senars);
  document.write("</ul>");
  document.write("</ol>");
  document.write("The total numbers of even numbers read has been: " + numparells);
    document.write("The total numbers of even numbers read has been: " + numsenars);
```